# Ways to analyse TTFB for a Joomla site

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo, server-response-time

My site's ttfb is very high.

[www.farafan-market.ir](https://www.farafan-market.ir/)

I used to use JCH-optimize plugin to enhance the page load. Then when I enabled Joomla's system-cache plugin, TTFB reduced to less than 1 second. But then after a while suddenly it got up to 3 or more seconds.

What ways are there to analyse TTFB in a Joomla site?
How can I realize what component or what part of the site causes this?

Comment: Try enabling Joomla's system debug option from the Global Configuration. This can give you useful information about things such as database query times.

Comment: There are some good suggestions in the answers to https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23291/120 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/7100/120 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/21028/120 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23125/120 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23301/120