# Why Is My Loading Time So Long?

Tags: joomla-3.x, helix3

I have a lot of loading time in my Joomla websites. The idle time is over 2 sec.
On the website I have 125 SQL queries.
I use Helix Ultimate with the SP Pagebuilder Pro
Link to my Website: http://www.wawi24.net/

Comment: do you use any plugin to optimize or cache?

Comment: I havent run any performance benchmarks of other tests, but tried loading your site on my phone (4G but bad location) and it took about 1 second

Answer (score 1):

I checked your website, you have messed up image urls. Below is the list of images your website is trying to load but failing and adding to the unwanted load time. Recheck your urls and you'll definitely see a increase in response time.

```
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/15/lieferantenverwaltung.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/28/angebote.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/28/vorgangsbersicht.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/28/vorgangsfortfhrung.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/29/vorgangsarten.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/05/kontoauszugsimport.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/05/mitarbeitereinschraenkungen.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/05/personeneinschraenkungen.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/13/listenfunktion.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/13/terminplaner.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/15/formulardesigner.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/15/auswertung.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/18/auswertung.jpg
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/19/druckfunktion.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/19/datenbankfelder.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/19/maskeneditor.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/25/datenzuordnung.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/25/datenexport.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/06/25/afs_logo_wei.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/14/adressverwaltung.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/14/adressdatenfeatures.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/15/artikelverwaltung.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/25/warengruppen.png
http://www.wawi24.net/images/2018/05/07/headmain.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are a couple of issues here

- Time To First Bye (TTFB)
- General performance

So, firstly, you're going to want to get your hosting providers to install a free SSL cerificate (Let's Encrypt) which will utilise HTTP/2.0 and improve the speed at which assets are fetch from the server.

The TTFB is something you hosting provider is going to have to look into. That said, sometimes it's simply a matter of where the datacenter is. For example, if you live in Europe, don't use a hosting provider in the US or Asia, simply because they are further away and the latency will be a lot higher.

In regards to the general performance, well you're using one of those horrible template frameworks which doo all kinds of fancy things for users, but are a terrible performance killer. This includes Helix, Warp, Gantry and the rest of them.
You ideally want to asyncronously load your assets. In Joomla 3, this is a little harder for Javascript due to the event listeners, but you can definitely do it for CSS, images and fonts.

Try using the LightHouse speed test with Google Chrome as you gradually make improvements