# Site has 2 seconds of server waiting time

Tags: joomla-3.x, performance, server-response-time

[image]

I have exhausted all the options (to the best of my knowledge) and there are still 2 seconds of server waiting time.

I have upgraded to the latest version of Joomla, jch optimize pro, jotcache, gzip, etc.

We are using a VPS with decent configurations.

Any clues will be helpful to find out the root cause.

Comment: Enable debug, inspect profiling information and database queries.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling server side caching can help.

For example, installing the free [LiteSpeed Cache extension for Joomla 3.x](https://www.litespeedtech.com/products/cache-plugins/joomla-acceleration/download) on a suitably configured LiteSpeed server can dramatically reduce the time to first byte (shown in yellow below):

[image]

Comment: I would also note it's better to cache at server level, rather than CMS level

Comment: Can I install  OpenLiteSpeed's cache module on my VPS which is using Apache server... please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Litespeed Cache will only work with a suitably configured Litespeed server. There may be other server side caching options available. For example SiteGround offer "Dynamic Cache" on GrowBig shared hosting plans or better. It's probably best to check with your hosting provider what is possible.